# How to hotlink an image in DOC file with Google API?

Tags: php, google-docs-api

I create new doc file on Google Docs, insert an image into it, and (there is no option to insert linked image, isn't it?) need to assign an URL to in so the image would be clickable.

```
$docs_service = new Google_Service_Docs($client);
$drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client); 

$document = new Google_Service_Docs_Document(array(
    'title' => $file_name
));
$document = $docs_service->documents->create($document);   

$requests[] =
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
        'insertText' => array(
            'location' => array(
                'index' => 1,
            ),
            'text' => "\n".$text
        )
    ));

$requests[] = new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
    'insertInlineImage' => array(
        'uri' => 'https://example.com/img.jpg',
        'location' => array(
            'index' => 1,
        ),
        'objectSize' => array(
            'height' => array(
                'magnitude' => 675,
                'unit' => 'PT',
            ),
            'width' => array(
                'magnitude' => 360,
                'unit' => 'PT',
            ),
        )
    )
));

$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(array(
    'requests' => $requests
));
$response = $docs_service->documents->batchUpdate($document->getDocumentId(), $batchUpdateRequest);

$doc = $docs_service->documents->get($document->getDocumentId(), ['fields' => 'body']);
```

But I can't find right API function. There is the method `setLinkUrl` of class `InlineImage`, but how to get an instance of `InlineImage`?

Another approach is iterating the document:

```
$doc = $docs_service->documents->get($document->getDocumentId(), ['fields' => 'body']);

foreach ($doc->body->content as $content) {
  print_r($content);
}
```

but the printed out nothing useful.

Comment: What is the name of the library that provide `Google_Service_Docs` and the other classes?

Answer (score 0):

In your showing script, a new Document is created using the Docs API, and an image is put into the created new Document. In this case, how about modifying your request body as follows? In this modification, UpdateTextStyleRequest is used.

#### From:

```
$requests[] = new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
    'insertInlineImage' => array(
        'uri' => 'https://example.com/img.jpg',
        'location' => array(
            'index' => 1,
        ),
        'objectSize' => array(
            'height' => array(
                'magnitude' => 675,
                'unit' => 'PT',
            ),
            'width' => array(
                'magnitude' => 360,
                'unit' => 'PT',
            ),
        )
    )
));
```

#### To:

```
$requests = [
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
        'insertInlineImage' => array(
            'uri' => 'https://example.com/img.jpg',
            'location' => array(
                'index' => 1,
            ),
            'objectSize' => array(
                'height' => array(
                    'magnitude' => 675,
                    'unit' => 'PT',
                ),
                'width' => array(
                    'magnitude' => 360,
                    'unit' => 'PT',
                ),
            )
        ),
    )),
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
        'updateTextStyle' => array(
            'range' => array(
                'startIndex' => 1,
                'endIndex' => 2,
            ),
            'textStyle' => array(
                'link' => array(
                    'url' => 'https://www.google.com', // Please set your URL.
                ),
            ),
            'fields' => 'link',
        ),
    )),
];
```

- When this modified request body is used, the hyperlink of `https://www.google.com` is set to the inserted image on Google Document.
- For example, if you want to retrieve `startIndex` and `endIndex` from the inserted image on Document, how about the following sample script?

  ```
    $doc = $docs_service->documents->get($document->getDocumentId(), ['fields' => 'body']);
    foreach ($doc->body->content as $content) {
        if (array_key_exists('paragraph', $content)) {
            foreach ($content->paragraph->elements as $element) {
                if (array_key_exists('inlineObjectElement', $element)) {
                    $startIndex = $element->startIndex;
                    $endIndex = $element->endIndex;
                    print_r(array($startIndex, $endIndex));
                }
            }
        }
    }
  ```

  - In the case of your script, the values of `$startIndex` and `$endIndex` are 1 and 2, respectively. Please use these values with `range` of `updateTextStyle` as the above modification.

#### Reference:

- [UpdateTextStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updatetextstylerequest)